# Facebook API: like a photo

Tags: facebook

In the Facebook API (REST), how do you like a photo?  There's a stream.addLike function, but you need the post_id, and I don't see a way to get the post_id of a photo (not the same as the pid or the object_id).

Comment: Impossible without a partnership with facebook

Answer (score 2):

You can now like a photo using Graph API, via a POST to the likes connection on a photo.  This did not work previously work but it does now (2011/09/16).  Not sure exactly when it got fixed but this one was an oversight for a very long after Graph API was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have an Id of Uploaded picture when you are adding this. e.g

```
        var client = new FacebookClient(Access_Token);

        JsonObject jsonResponse = client.Get("me/feed") as JsonObject;
        string feed_ID = string.Empty;
        foreach (var account in (JsonArray)jsonResponse["data"])
        {
            feed_ID = (string)(((JsonObject)account)["id"]);
            goto Next;
        }
    Next: { };
```

let us say you have got the id of your latest picture uploeded is 12345123_5488224848
now you want to update like this picture. write the following code.

```
      var client2 = new FacebookClient(Access_Token);
      clientS.Post("12345123_5488224848/likes");
```

all done. check the status of photo after this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the actual photo is classes as the same type of entity os a wallpost, so asloon as you can aquire the stream_id for the photo, it the comments that are attached to the photo you can set `stream.addLink` found http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.addLike Here

By getting the post_id via the photos.get method you should be able to set a comment adn like the object via the stream.addLike.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: You can't get the post_id from photos.get which is the whole problem, you can only attain the object_id and pid.  And I don't see a way to go from those to post_id.

Comment: Have you tried a cross table join using FQL Like so: SELECT pid, aid, owner, src, src_big, src_small, link, caption, created 
FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=<uid>) 
AND aid=<aid> AND pid IN (pid)

Comment: That doesn't get the post_id.  I found out that this is impossible unless you have a partnership with facebook :D

Comment: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: I think when a user adds a photo the photo goes into the desired folder, and facebook auto creates a templatized stream for that image, so when you like an image your actually liking the generated stream item. not 100% sure but that's how I would develop it to keep the entities separate.

Comment: I talked with someone who had a partnership with facebook, in person, no reference other than that

Answer (score 0):

```
   var client = new FacebookClient(Access_Token);

    JsonObject jsonResponse = client.Get("me/feed") as JsonObject;
    string feed_ID = string.Empty;
    foreach (var account in (JsonArray)jsonResponse["data"])
    {
        feed_ID = (string)(((JsonObject)account)["id"]);
        goto Next;
    }
Next: { };
```